# Use JSONDecoder to unpack nested JSON values

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

How can I get the third-level values from this JSON data?

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1669690663119337",
      "name": "Event1",
      "attending_count": 17,
      "cover": {
        "offset_x": 0,
        "offset_y": 50,
        "source": "https://imageurl",
        "id": "1769679396399074"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "130418660933615",
      "name": "Event2",
      "attending_count": 923,
      "cover": {
        "offset_x": 0,
        "offset_y": 50,
        "source": "https://imageurl",
        "id": "10156609677937586"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "1883372648594017",
      "name": "Event3",
      "attending_count": 1695,
      "cover": {
        "offset_x": 0,
        "offset_y": 50,
        "source": "imageurl",
        "id": "10156575272607586"
      }
    }
```

For second-level values (id,name,attending_count), im using these lines of code:

```
struct JsonFromWeb: Codable {
    let data: [Course]
}

struct Course: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let name: String?
    let attending_count: Int?
}


class JsonViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var eventTable: UITableView!

    var event = [Course]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            let jsonUrlString = "https://www.jsonurl.url/"
            guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }
            print(jsonUrlString)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
                guard let data = data else { return }
                do {
                    let courses = try JSONDecoder().decode(JsonFromWeb.self, from: data)
                    self.event = courses.data
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.eventTable.reloadData()
                    }
                } catch let jsonErr {
                    print("Error jsonErr", jsonErr)
                }
                }.resume()
        }

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return event.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventCell") as? UserEventsTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.nameLabel.text = event[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly the same pattern as for the second level. You have to create a separate struct / class for any dictionary. The name of the struct is arbitrary. The property in the parent struct / class must match the dictionary key (in this case `cover`)

```
struct JsonFromWeb: Codable {
    let data: [Course]
}

struct Course: Codable {

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case attendingCount = "attending_count"
        case id, name, cover
    }
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let attendingCount: Int
    let cover: Cover
}    

struct Cover : Codable {

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case offsetX = "offset_x"
        case offsetY = "offset_y"
        case source, id
    }
    let offsetX: Int
    let offsetY: Int
    let source: String
    let id: String
}
```

Note:

**Never** use this syntax

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventCell") as? UserEventsTableViewCell else { 
    return UITableViewCell() 
}
```

This is one of the few cases where force unwrapping is recommended to discover design errors. If everything is hooked up correctly the code **must not** crash. And use the `dequeue` API which returns always a valid cell:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventCell", for: indexPath) as! UserEventsTableViewCell
```

Comment: First, thank you very much for answering so quickly. But can you help me also adding this "source" variable to table, like i added "name" variable? That would make my day :)
 Using this:
let courses = try JSONDecoder().decode(JsonFromWeb.self, from: data)
self.event = courses.data

Comment: What is the problem? Your code is supposed to work. If no data are displayed the error is related to the custom table view cell

Comment: When i replace my part of code with your code, then error appears: (CodingKeys in _BD6BE31D58877246570CAEB111C1E2ED).data, Foundation.(_JSONKey in _12768CA107A31EF2DCE034FD75B541C9)(stringValue: "Index 17", intValue: Optional(17))], debugDescription: "No value associated with key cover (\"cover\").", underlyingError: nil))

And i should not use this with variables? : cell.nameLabel.text = event[indexPath.row].name

Comment: If `cover` can be `nil` than make `cover` optional: `let cover: Cover?`

Comment: Yes, now it works. Thank you again, you helped me alot! :)